# architecture of complex android app

Tags: android, architecture, state-machine

I'm writing a moderately complex Android app, which includes an always running 'network' service.

The app is highly stateful, and can change state by either UI or network data (pushed down a nearly-always open TCP connection, which is kept alive by 'application pings', a.k.a. 'keep alives').

(My question is not about whether a nearly-always open TCP is a good idea or not.)

On other platforms, I have used a state machine to keep things sane.

On Android it looks like I have three choices:

1. One huge activity and a state machine, communications via a bound service.
2. 15+ Activities and a state machine which fires intents on state changes.
3. 15+ Activities and no state machine - just try to glue it all together with intents.

My questions are:

- Have others used explicit state machines in Android apps?
- Is it a good idea, or it there a better way in Android?
- Do other apps have this level of state complexity?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at the QP state machine framework port to Android-NDK (http://www.state-machine.com/android).